# Close the message button

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
import os
import Tkinter

gui = Tkinter.Tk()  
gui.geometry("300x200")
messagebutton1 = Tkinter.Button(gui,text='Process Completed')
messagebutton1.place(x=80,y=80)
```

This is my example.I need to close this "process Completed" message button by clicking.What is the syntax for that.can you please guide me.

Comment: What do you mean by `close`?

Comment: While message button that "Process Completed" will appeared,by clicking button needs to close the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `destroy` method to close `Tk`.

```
import os
import Tkinter

def close():
    gui.destroy()

gui = Tkinter.Tk()  
gui.geometry("300x200")
messagebutton1 = Tkinter.Button(gui,text='Process Completed', command=close)
messagebutton1.place(x=80,y=80)

gui.mainloop()
```